# Как можно сэмулировать браузер сафари на виндовс

Tags: javascript, html, css

Всем привет, хотел узнать , есть ли способы сэмулировать сафари браузер на виндовс? Порой бывает что занимаюсь версткой, и на винде во всех браузерах все хорошо, а на маках в Сафари браузере постоянно какая-то фигня происходит.

Comment: нельзя. используй либо сторонние сервисы, либо виртуальные машины, либо реальные устройства

Comment: Есть приложение MultiBrowser, но оно платное.